# Can we skip this continuous variable main effect in the interaction?

Tags: modeling

Suppose I have a simple model like this:

y ~ alpha_1*x_1 + alpha_2*x_2 + beta*x_1*x_2

x_1 is a dummy variable, x_2 is a continuous variable.

If alpha_2 is insignificant, but beta is significant. Can I skip alpha_2 in the model, and write the final model as:
y ~ alpha_1*x_1 + beta*x_1*x_2

I recalled that in Statistic textbook, if we want to use interaction, we need to have main effect. But what is the underlying rationale for this usage?

Thanks in advance for any comments.

Eric

Comment: Can anyone answer this question?